# Deriving $\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}-i\frac{d}{dy})$ Intuitively

Tags: complex-analysis

Without the [usual math](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92624/why-partial-and-bar-partial-defined-in-that-way-the-wirtinger-derivativ) (i.e. the usual algebra you use to define these things), why should we want to define

$$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}-i\frac{d}{dy})$$
$$\frac{d}{d\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}+i\frac{d}{dy})$$

I keep forgetting the $\tfrac{1}{2}$ and keep forgetting the minus signs.

If we re-write $-i$ as $-i=\tfrac{1}{i}$ we can rewrite the above as

$$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dy})$$
$$\frac{d}{d\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dy})$$

which is a bit more intuitive since $\bar{z}$ is on the L.H.S. & there's a corresponding minus R.H.S. etc... but this still isn't intuitive enough - we can incorrectly derive them using something stupid like

$$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{d}{d(x+iy)} = \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{d}{d(iy)} = \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{i} \frac{d}{dy}$$

Is there a way to make this a bit nicer/logical and to include to $2$?

$$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{d}{d[2(x+iy)]} = ...$$

Maybe with [pictures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761827/geometric-derivation-of-the-d-bar-operator-frac-partial-partial-z-frac)?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{w\to 0} \frac{f(z+w)-f(z)}{w}$ is (if it exists) the average of $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ and $\frac{1}{i} \lim_{k\to 0} \frac{f(z+ik)-f(z)}{k}$, where $w$ is complex, and $h,k$ are real.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-wirtinger-derivatives and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92624/why-partial-and-bar-partial-defined-in-that-way-the-wirtinger-derivativ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The derivative $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ is completely fixed by linearity and two further requirements:

- it should kill $\bar z=x-iy$ (this tells that $\partial_z\sim \partial_x-i\partial_y$)
- $\partial_zz=1$ (this fixes the $\frac12$-factor).

Answer (score 4):

When you look at derivations, you look at the *dual* space of differential, you are not making some sort of funny division between $d$ and $dz$. If you consider the map sending $\{dx,dy\}$ to $\{dz,d\bar{z}\}$, written with respect to the basis $\{dx,dy\}$, you get
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\i&-i\end{pmatrix}$$
Now you want a map $B$ on the dual such that $\langle v, w^*\rangle=\langle Av, B^*w^*\rangle$ and so $B^{-1}=A^t$.
Therefore
$$B=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\\-i&i\end{pmatrix}\;.$$

Long story short, you are looking at a basis change on the dual space, so the related matrix is the transpose of the inverse of the original basis change.